# Linkedin API readout Profile skills

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, linkedin-api

Can the **Linkedin API** be used to readout a **profile’s skills** and display them on any **website** with the JS rest API?

Comment: Have you checked out docs? (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api)

Comment: @biera Yes, but it is not explicitly written that it can readout profile skills. (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile)

Comment: You can: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/full-profile